# How to Use `import.meta` When Testing With Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs

I am writing Node.js code (in TypeScript) using ESModules and I need access to `__dirname`. In order to access the ESM equivalent of `__dirname` in CommonJS, I call `dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))`. I am also writing tests in Jest with TypeScript. Using [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started) guide, I set up Babel. When I run the `jest` command, I get

```
const DIRNAME = (0, _path.dirname)((0, _url.fileURLToPath)(import.meta.url));
                                                                      ^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module
```

Here are the files I wrote

*`someCode.ts`:*

```
import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const DIRNAME = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

export const x = 5;
```

*`someCode.test.ts`:*

```
import { x } from "./someCode";

it("Returns 5 as the result", () => {
    expect(x).toEqual(5);
});
```

*`.babelrc.json`:*

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }],
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
}
```

*`tsconfig.json:`*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.js"]
}
```

*`package.json`:*

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "typescript": "^4.1.2"
    }
}
```

**Environment:**

- Node: 14.1.0
- *See `package.json` for module versions*

Comment: You're following a common guide that uses CommonJS modules. For native ESM see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules

Comment: I am looking for an answer to the same question. Moving Jest to ESM modules seems excessive.

Answer (score 33):

We are using `import.meta.url` to make use of web workers, for example using the [native worker support in Webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/). That works great but fails when running the Jest tests.

`babel-vite-preset` does *not* handle this as far as I can tell. The top answer about extracting and mocking the code that uses `import.meta` does work but is unwieldy.

I found the currently best solution is to use [babel-plugin-transform-import-meta](https://github.com/javiertury/babel-plugin-transform-import-meta). That simple plugin replaces the `import.meta.url` syntax with Node.js code to retrieve the URL to the current file, so it works nicely in tests. Note that you will only want to have this plugin active when running the tests.

Comment: Thanks, exactly my needs !

Comment: How do you make it work only in jest? I was trying to get something working with create-react-app 5 / webpack 5 here but couldn't get the tests to run https://github.com/cmdcolin/cra-webpack5-web-worker-example

Comment: @ColinD the way I did this was to only add the plugin when in the "test" environment, something like this in `babel.config.js`: https://gist.github.com/cmlenz/da2b8b9aa959d24b2d300a8a04a23727. Don't know about CRA

Comment: awesome, thanks! random other question: does it actually run in a "worker" when it uses jest this way?

Comment: @ColinD no, I think in general you test the code running from the worker, but without the worker itself. I don't think you can really test workers themselves in Jest.

Comment: For anyone who is reading env instead url, you can use the following package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env

Answer (score 21):

## The solution: Modularize the ESM code and mock it.

I ran into this issue recently, as well, and I ended up having to:

1. Export the ESM specific issue, e.g. `import.meta` functionality, into it's own, "utils" file/function.
2. Then create a mock function that doesn't require ESM specific functionality in a **mocks** directory.
3. in the files that use that functionality, declare `jest.mock("/path/to/that/file.ts")`

The process will look something like this:

### The Original File Structure

```
src/
--/someCode.ts
--/__tests__/
/--/--/someCode.test.ts
```

```
// someCode.ts
...
const getApiUrl = () => { 
  ...
  const url = import.meta.env.SOME_ENV_VAR_HERE;
  ...
  return url;
};
...
```

The New File Structure

### Heading

```
src/
--/someCode.ts
--/utils.js
--/__mocks__/
--/--/utils.ts
--/__tests__/
--/--/someCome.test.ts
```

and then in the files themselves:

```
// someCode.ts
...
import { getApiUrl } from "./utils.ts";
...

// utils.js
export const getApiUrl = () => {...};
```

and for the tests:

```
// __mocks__/utils.ts
export const getApiUrl = jest.fn(() => 'some.url');

// __tests__/utils.test.ts
...
jest.mock("src/util.ts");
...
describe(...);
```

Comment: This is what led to my solution. The only difference being doing something like this:
```
jest.mock('$lib/variables', () => ({
 __esModule: true,
 variables: {
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:2222'
 }
}));
```

Comment: @TimoHermans could you post the solution worked for you  in answer

Comment: this solution is a little bit wonky. It works in the spec of root itself, but can cause mocks of files elsewhere to not properly import for some reason. I am looking into the babel solution now

Comment: This has solved the problem for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: for every file in different path there needs to be a separate utils with this solution. because every util will return its own url. i dont think this is a sustainable solution

Answer (score 7):

Based on [this PR](https://github.com/bestofjs/bestofjs-webui/pull/138/files), you can get it running on Jest by changing several things:

1. Update all `import.meta.env` syntax to `process.env`
   e.g.:

   ```js
   process.env.VITE_APP_BASE_URL
   ```
2. Add environment variable definition in the `vite.config.ts`
   e.g.:

   ```js
   export default defineConfig((props) => {
       const env = loadEnv(props.mode, process.cwd(), "VITE_APP");
       const envWithProcessPrefix = {
         "process.env": `${JSON.stringify(env)}`,
       };

       return {
           plugins: [
               react(),
           ],
           define: envWithProcessPrefix,
          }
       })
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that is so ridiculous i don't even believed when it worked:

Create a commonjs file, like "currentPath.cjs", Inside it put something like:

```
module.exports = __dirname;
```

In your module use:

```
import * as currentPath from "./currentPath.cjs";
console.log(currentPath.default);
```

And watch the magic happen.
PS: Use the path.normalize() before using it on anything.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I fix it with a babel plugin: [search-and-replace](https://github.com/jean-smaug/babel-plugin-search-and-replace/blob/42bfe5335aaa4cc22fb1161ca33445a2b4e24aba/lib/index.js)

In my code I changed all `import.meta.url` with `import_meta_url`

And I add the plugin to babel config to change it by `import.meta.url` in development and production and by `resolve(__dirname, 'workers')`

I was able to do so because it matched all my cases, if your `import_meta_url` needs to be replaced with different stings in different scenarios you would need to use `import_meta_url_1` `import_meta_url_2` etc. for instance

finally my `babel.config.js`

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    return {
      presets: ['next/babel'],
      plugins: [
        [
          'search-and-replace',
          {
            rules: [
              {
                searchTemplateStrings: true,
                search: 'import_meta_url',
                replace: resolve(__dirname, 'workers'),
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      ],
    };
  }

  return {
    presets: ['next/babel'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'search-and-replace',
        {
          rules: [
            {
              searchTemplateStrings: true,
              search: 'import_meta_url',
              replace: 'import.meta.url',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

GL

Comment: I have used the same config in my babel.config.js but it didn't work. I am getting following error `TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid base URL`

Comment: `search-and-replace` package name has been updated to `babel-plugin-search-and-replace`

Answer (score 3):

[babel-vite-preset](https://github.com/OpenSourceRaidGuild/babel-vite)

I think this one is great.

non-official.

you can choose to use it only `babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env` plugin or use whole preset and set config like below

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "babel-preset-vite",
      {
        "env": true, // defaults to true
        "glob": false // defaults to true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. The only issue was when other properties other than `env` or `glob` are accessed e.g `import.meta.hot` then it would not work

Comment: This plugin works for me!. Install `yarn add -D  babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env ` then, in babel.config.js add `{
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env"]
}`

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue. I was able to resolve the issue by dynamically inserting a correct value during babel processing. Instead of the `search-and-replace` babel plugin that was suggested, I used the [codegen macro for babel](https://github.com/kentcdodds/codegen.macro).

```
// someCode.ts
import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import codegen from 'codegen.macro';

const DIRNAME = dirname(fileURLToPath(codegen`module.exports = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" ? "{ADD VALID VALUE FOR TESTS}" : "import.meta.url"`));

export const x = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

1.change your tsconfig with below

```
compilerOptions": {
       "module": "esnext",
       //... remaining options 
     }
```

2.add below in jest.config

```
  globals: {
     "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: false,
       useESM: true,
      babelConfig: true,
       plugins: ["babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env"],
     },
    },
   transform: {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts)$": "babel-jest",
    }
`
```

3.Now it will start giving error Cannot use import.meta To resolve this problem add below in babel config:
`

```
module.exports = function (api) {
 
 api.cache(true);
  const presets = [
   ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
  "@babel/preset-typescript",
  "@babel/preset-react",
];

return {
  presets,
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env",
   ],
  };
 };`
```

@babel/plugin-transform-runtime, babel-plugin-transform-import-meta these plugins will help you to resolve this problem

Comment: If you're using Vite, I think this has to be one of the simplest ways to get things working.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Jest and ESM while tried to access `__dirname` in a new way.
It should be mentioned, there is no `@babel` in my project, but I think the solution is still reliable.

I have tried to change `module` and `target` in `tsconfig.json` for no result.

Also, I modified the `jest.config.cjs` file like shown below. Still no result.

```js
{
  ...
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    NODE_OPTIONS: '--experimental-vm-modules',
  }
  ...
}
```

Finally, the workaround I have found in [pretter-plugin-xml package.json](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-xml/blob/c4abf07fe1c82b664ba07c11a6cc88b7b475032c/package.json#L11) (that contains [import.meta.url in tests](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-xml/blob/c4abf07fe1c82b664ba07c11a6cc88b7b475032c/test/format.test.js#L6)) works for me.
I have changed `package.json:scripts:test` from `jest` to explicit jest.js call:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

It is similar to settings the `NODE_OPTIONS="--experimental-vm-modules"` environment variable, however the provided solution seems to be cross-platform.

---

My `tsconfig.json:compilerOptions` snippet:

```json
{
  ...
  "module": "NodeNext",
  "target": "es2016",
  ...
}
```

The `jest.config.cjs`:

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',

    // Without this option,
    // error `The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when ...` reveals
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],

    // No import resolution, otherwise
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
    },

    // Process infinitely run, if the option is not set
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
            'ts-jest',
            {
                useESM: true,
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: The only thing that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using [`@swc/jest`](https://swc.rs/docs/usage/jest) to transform files for jest, its optimiser's global var replacement feature can substitute values for `import.meta.env.*` values globally.

With this config `import.meta.env.MODE` is `'development'` during test runs:

```js
// jest.config.js
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
export default {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": [
      "@swc/jest",
      {
        jsc: {
          transform: {
            optimizer: {
              globals: {
                vars: {
                  "import.meta.env.MODE": "'development'",
                },
              },
            },
            // Everything below here is just my own config, probably not relevant
            react: {
              runtime: "automatic",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts", ".tsx"],
  testEnvironment: "<rootDir>/jest-environment-jsdom.ts",
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [".(fixtures|mock|utils).tsx?$"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest-setup.ts"],
  resetMocks: true,
  resetModules: true,
};
```

If you need to mock different values in tests, rewrite the env property to a global object you create in jest-setup:

```
// use this in the jest config above
vars: {
  "import.meta.env.MODE": "__import_meta_env",
}
```

```js
// jest-setup.ts
(global as any).__import_meta_env = {
  MODE: "development",
};
```

```js
// import-meta.test.ts
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

test("import.meta.env is rewritten to __import_meta_env", () => {
  expect(import.meta.env).toBe((global as any).__import_meta_env);
});

test('import.meta.env.MODE is "development"', () => {
  expect(import.meta.env.MODE).toBe("development");
});

describe("something is different in production mode", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Can also just directly assign, e.g. import.meta.env.MODE = 'production'
    jest.replaceProperty(import.meta.env, "MODE", "production");
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  test('import.meta.env.MODE can be changed to "production"', () => {
    console.log(import.meta.env);
    expect(import.meta.env.MODE).toBe("production");
  });
});

test('import.meta.env.MODE is "development" again', () => {
  expect(import.meta.env.MODE).toBe("development");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `tsconfig.json` change  to

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ES2020",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.js"]
}
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a Node.js, Express, TypeScript, Jest, ts-jext project. The issue, for me, was getting the jest.config.json configured correctly.

I'm posting my files in case this helps someone.

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "express-react",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "npm run build && npm run dev",
    "build": "npm run format && npm run lint && npm run tsc",
    "start:prod": "npm run build && node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node dist/index.js",
    "start": "npm run start:prod",
    "dev": "cross-env-shell DEBUG=express:* node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm ./src/index.ts",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.ts\"",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext 'ts,json'",
    "tsc": "tsc",

    "test": "cross-env-shell TS_JEST_LOG=ts-jest.jog NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest --detectOpenHandles --verbose --testTimeout 20000 --coverage=true --reporters=default --json --debug --outputFile=./test/log.json",
    "test:list": "jest --detectOpenHandles --coverage=true --listTests --debug"

  },
  "dependencies": {

    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.3.1",
    "http-errors": "^1.6.3",
    "into-stream": "^7.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "save-dev": "0.0.1-security",
    "sharp": "^0.30.4",
    "supertest": "^6.2.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.9.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/debug": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/express-fileupload": "^1.2.2",
    "@types/http-errors": "^1.8.2",
    "@types/into-stream": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.31",
    "@types/sharp": "^0.30.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.22.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

**TSCONFIG.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "express-react",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "npm run build && npm run dev",
    "build": "npm run format && npm run lint && npm run tsc",
    "start:prod": "npm run build && node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node dist/index.js",
    "start": "npm run start:prod",
    "dev": "cross-env-shell DEBUG=express:* node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm ./src/index.ts",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.ts\"",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext 'ts,json'",
    "tsc": "tsc",

    "test": "cross-env-shell TS_JEST_LOG=ts-jest.jog NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest --detectOpenHandles --verbose --testTimeout 20000 --coverage=true --reporters=default --json --debug --outputFile=./test/log.json",
    "test:list": "jest --detectOpenHandles --coverage=true --listTests --debug"

  },
  "dependencies": {

    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.3.1",
    "http-errors": "^1.6.3",
    "into-stream": "^7.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "save-dev": "0.0.1-security",
    "sharp": "^0.30.4",
    "supertest": "^6.2.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.9.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/debug": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/express-fileupload": "^1.2.2",
    "@types/http-errors": "^1.8.2",
    "@types/into-stream": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.31",
    "@types/sharp": "^0.30.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.22.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

**JEST.CONFIG.JS**

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "ts", "json", "node"],
  roots: ["./"],
  testMatch: ["./**/*.test.ts"],
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "./node_modules/",
    "./dist/",
    "./files/",
    "./public/",
  ],
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
      useESM: true
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Looks like your "TSCONFIG.JSON" is actually a repeat of your package.json

Answer (score 0):

None of the current answers worked for me. The best and more simple solution is to use this package.

https://github.com/ThomZz/ts-jest-mock-import-meta+

```
npm install -D ts-jest-mock-import-meta
```

and then for ts-jest > 29.0.0, add to your jest.config

```
{
  // [...]
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        diagnostics: {
          ignoreCodes: [1343]
        },
        astTransformers: {
          before: [
            {
              path: 'node_modules/ts-jest-mock-import-meta',  // or, alternatively, 'ts-jest-mock-import-meta' directly, without node_modules.
              options: { metaObjectReplacement: { url: 'https://www.url.com' } }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Consider whether a refactoring could circumvent the problem**

I had the same problem, but then realized that the code I wanted to test didn't really depend on `import.meta` at all. So, instead of solving the import problem, I circumvented this problem through a **refactoring**: *extracting the tested code to a pure function in a separate file that didn't need any (indirect) imports of `import.meta`*.

## Before

`complex.ts`

```
import { X_VAL } from "../_env.js"; // uses import.meta

function complexLogic(y: Y): Z {
  ...
  const z = X_VAL + y; // logic that is tested
  ...
  return z;
}
```

`complex.test.ts`

```
import { complexLogic } from "./complex.js";
describe("complex logic processing", () => {
  test("take x,y and produce z", () => {
    ...
    const actual = complexLogic(y);
    expect(actual).toEqual(z);
  });
});
```

## AFTER

`processing.ts`

```
// pure function
export function processingLogic(x: X, y: Y): Z {
   return x + y // logic that is tested
}
```

`complex.ts`

```
import "../_env.js"; // uses import.meta
import { processingLogic } from "./processing.js";
function complexLogic(y: Y): Z {
  ...
  const z = processingLogic(X_VAL, y);
  ...
  return z;
}
```

`processing.test.ts`

```
import { processingLogic } from "./processing.js";
describe("processing", () => {
  test("take x,y and produce z", () => {
    ...
    const actual = processingLogic(x, y);
    expect(actual).toEqual(z);
  });
});
```